# generic java structure to store multiple object types and keys defined

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am looking to see whats out there in collections in any java framework like apache or guava that will let me handle the below. I am also open to consider any custom implementations if required

Basically I have

1. Inventory object , the inventory number field will help identify a
   unique inventory object
2. Order object the order number field will
   help identify a unique order
3. OrderItem Object, the order number and
   item number fields will help identify a unique order (the key here
   is composite)

I can have more objects come in later on with different attributes and having composite key types. Also I dont want to put the orderItem inside the order object

Basically I am looking to see if there is a elegant way to build a generic structure where in I can define the keys that will help identify a object and retrieve the object dynamically using the key? I should be able to specify composite key types as well.

structure.put(invKey, inventory);
structure.put(orderKey, order);
structure.put(orderItemKey, orderItem) (the key here is composite of two attributes)

Comment: use java.util.HashMap or ConcurrentHashmap depending on your requirement of multiuser/concurrent update or not.

Comment: But how will that support storing different object types with different key types?

Comment: In 99% of cases, it's just a _bad idea_ to put different types in the same map.  Use different `Map` objects for each mapping.